# Jquery get array of input element values within a common parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, selector

I have a jquery application where I am templating an html block that contains 3 textfields. I need to get the values of the text fields within a specific block. the identifiers are replicated in all blocks.

Sample Code

```
<div>
  <div class="htmlBlock">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="myInput1" type="text">
        <input class="myInput2" type="text">
        <input class="myInput3" type="text">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="myInput1" type="text">
        <input class="myInput2" type="text">
        <input class="myInput3" type="text">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input class="myInput1" type="text">
        <input class="myInput2" type="text">
        <input class="myInput3" type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
   <button class="clickMe">Click to get values of this block</button>
  </div>
  <div class="htmlBlock">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="myInput1" type="text">
        <input class="myInput2" type="text">
        <input class="myInput3" type="text">
      </li>
    </ul>
  <button class="clickMe">Click to get values of this block</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I click the `.clickMe` button I want to call `$('.myInput').val()` and get the value only within the block that the button is located.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
$('button.clickMe').on('click', function() {
    var block = $(this).closest('.htmlBlock');
    var inputs = block.find('input[type="text"]');
    // .myInput1 values as an array.
    var myInput1Vals = block.find('.myInput1').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    });
    // Do what you want to do
});
```

I didn't use `$('.myInput').val()`, since you have different classes on each input. But you can loop through them, do whatever you want with them and they will all be localized within that block.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWjkU/)

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWjkU/1/) converts it to an array that is not a jQuery object using `.toArray()` after the `.map`.

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the values by class name. I modified the example to be more accurate to the situation. I woud like to get an array of .myInput1

Comment: that last one returned an empty array. this first one worked when i changed it to var block = $(this).closest('.paramList');
        block.find(paramVal.push($('.customParamValue').val())); but it only found one value when there was multiple

Comment: I just added a link to a fiddle that shows `myInput1Vals` as not being empty at all. They reason yours is only returning one value is because jQuery only returns the `val()` of the first in the set.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button.clickMe').on('click', function() {
    var values = $(this).closest('.htmlBlock').find('input[type="text"]').map(function(){
                     return this.value;
                 }).get();
});
```